# failed to register error on push notification mobilefirst 8.0

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

In my application I use MobileFirst Platform push notification,

```
  MFPPush.registerDevice(
     function(successResponse) {
          alert("Successfully registered");
     },
     function(failureResponse) {
          alert("Failed to register"+failureResponse);
      }
  );
```

I get the following error,

> "Failed to register
>   com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException
>   :Response:status=400,Text:"Invalid request body JSON mapping
>   failed",Error Message:Bad Request"

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a scope "push.mobileclient" ? If not please got to Security and create above scope . After that add above block inside success callback of `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then()`.